# Xamarin Forms - PanGestureRecognizer on item in ListView influence on the next hidden items by steps

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a ListView and set the items by listView.ItemsSource = list;
On every item in the xml I have a GestureRecognizer - PanGestureRecognizer and PanUpdated="PanUpdateFunction".

Well, on this function I get item by sender parameter and make some calculations to initialize the X that I need.

```cs
Frame frameThis = (Frame)sender;
var calcXScale = -((frameThis.Width / 7) * 5);
var scalePixels = -20;
switch (e.StatusType)
  {
    case GestureStatus.Running:
      if (e.TotalX < scalePixels)
      {
        await frameThis.TranslateTo(calcXScale, 0, 175, Easing.Linear);
        break;
      }
      if (e.TotalX > -(scalePixels))
      {
        await frameThis.TranslateTo(0, 0, 175, Easing.Linear);
        break;
      }

      break;
  }
}
```

When I slide the element to left and the result is more than my target, the element goes to left and that what I need to. But there is something like a bug - the next item in ListView that are hided from the screen also slides to left and the next, and the next, etc.

I mean: on the screen view I have 4 items and 10 hided. When I slide the first and I scroll to the bottom, the 5th and the 9th is also slided to left. If I slide 2nd, the 6th and the 10th are slided.

Comment: Sounds like the backing cell is reused and the hided status is also reused.

Comment: @Demogog well, I will try with custom CellView, may be you're right.

Comment: @Demogog,I guess the problem you are experiencing is because of the Caching Strategy of listview. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RetainElement as a caching strategy for your ListView:

```
<ListView CachingStrategy="RetainElement">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <!-- ... -->
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: It's not working. In my case I use CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" but with this change to CachingStrategy="RetainElement" the bug isn't fixed. :(